# Почему одна программа выполняется быстрее?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, производительность

У меня есть два кода, решающих одну и ту же задачу. Но почему то одна выполняется быстрее другой. И у меня вопрос из-за чего скорость одной мешьне.

код медленной программы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int closeNumber(vector<int> N, int number, int size) {
    int l = 0;
    int r = size - 1; 

    while (r - l > 1) {    
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;

        if (number > N[mid]) {
            l = mid;
        } 
        else {
            r = mid;
        } 
    }   

    if (N[r] - number < number - N[l]) {
        return N[r];
    }

    return N[l];
}

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    vector<int> N(n);
    vector<int> K(k);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> N[i];
    
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cin >> number;

        cout << closeNumber(N, number, n) << endl;
    }
    


    return 0;
}
```

код программы быстрой

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int n, k, x;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int arr[100000];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    for (int h = 0; h < k; h++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        int L = 0;
        int R = n - 1;

        while (R - L > 1)
        {
            int M = (R + L) / 2;

            if (arr[M] < x)
                L = M;
            else
                R = M;
        }
 
        if (x - arr[L] <= arr[R] - x) cout << arr[L] << endl;
        else cout << arr[R] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну как минимум в медленном коде происходит вызов функции в цикле. Появляются дополнительные расходы

Comment: `closeNumber(vector<int> N` - вы копируете вектор, что долго и не нужно. Передавайте его как ссылку.

Comment: Передайте вектор перемещением, но, все равно обе варианта медленные _ есть куда лучше способы решения.... .

Comment: В обоих случаях можно ещё ввести ветку `number == N[mid]`, тогда будет несколько быстрее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Простите, что как ответ, но особо не наблюдаю.

Скомпилировал и прогнал для N = 100000 и K = 10000 обе.

На моей машине с выводом в файл быстрая отработала за 35 мс. Медленная - за 224 мс.

Как только я убрал, гм... очень тяжеловесную передачу вектора по значению и заменил на

```
int closeNumber(const vector<int>& N, int number, int size) {
```

медленная отработала за те же 35 мс.

В пределах погрешности они одинаковы - если не копировать каждый раз большие массивы данных.

**Update**

Переписал поиск с использованием стандартных алгоритмов:

```
int closeNumber(const vector<int>& N, int number)
{
    auto m = lower_bound(N.begin(),N.end(),number);
    if (m == N.end())   return N[N.size()-1];
    if (m == N.begin()) return N[0];
    if (*m + *(m-1) < 2*number) return *m;
    return *--m;
}
```

Эксперимент с данными `N[i] = i*4` и одной и той же последовательностью из 10000 случайных запросов.

```
Быстрая программа                - 33,9±1,4 мс
Исправленная медленная программа - 33,7±1,3 мс
Новая программа                  - 33,5±2,2 мс
```

Погрешность - исходя из 100 запусков программы.

Выводы об одинаковой скорости делайте сами :)

Comment: Думаю что слово "издевательская" подразумевает, что автор знает что делает. Кажется, это не так. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, наверное половина программеров на С++ не отдают себе отчета, что вектор (в отличии от тривиального массива) копируется при передаче в функцию

Comment: По моему  первое условие if (m == N.end()) лишнее, во вторых lower_bound    применяется  для упорядоченных последовательностей.  И , по мне, можете найти решение проще, но это к вопросу не имеет отношение

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, `lower_bound применяется для упорядоченных последовательностей` - похоже, что автору вопроса это и нужно, раз он реализует бинарный поиск.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Если убрать это условие, то что будет, когда `m == N.end()`? Мы же тогда не можем выполнить проверку `if (*m...` из-за возможного разыменования `N.end()`. Об упорядоченности уже сказано выше.